# django keyword can't be an expression

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I am trying to create a query where I get a filtered list.

The model that I am calling the query on is:

```
class WorkoutRecord(models.Model):

    challenge = models.ForeignKey(Challenge)

    workout_email_sent = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)

    status = models.IntegerField(default=1)
```

My query is:

```
L = WorkoutRecord.objects.filter(status = 1, challenge.user = request.user, workout_email_sent__lt = today)
```

The error message I am getting is:

> keyword can't be an expression

I know the issue is on the `challenge.user = request.user` part of the query but I'm not sure how to write the query so it filters on this `ForeignKey` properly.

Comment: Just a friendly advice - http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/ :-)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Use __ to follow foreign key relationships in a queryset:

```
L = WorkoutRecord.objects.filter(status=1, challenge__user=request.user, workout_email_sent__lt=today)
```